# HTML - View Table in browser

Tags: html, background-color

I am trying to use table to create a song list in my website, but for some reason, when I view my webpage in browser (Chrome, Firefox), the table automatically added a light blue color background on every other row. I tried many ways but I just can't get rid off the background color.

I appreciate you help!

Comment: Please, provide some code so we can have some clue about your problem..

Comment: No mainstream browser will do that by default. You are either using something really obscure, or you have code to style it that way explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

A CSS style is being applied to your table.  Each browser had a developer tool to help you find stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

better to define table as transparent with CSS . Happening because browser adds its own effect if nothing is passed to it .. Browser do this with hope that user may like what it is rendering